# How do you bind the DataContext of a Control to the DataContext of its Content in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datacontext

I tried this:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Content.DataContext");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tab, DataContextProperty, binding);
```

It isn't working. I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried doing this declaritively?  (through xaml)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a source for the binding.  It is therefore using the local DataContext of the `tab` element.  Since the `tab` element doesn't yet have a DataContext (it's what you're trying to set), let alone one for which the path `Content.DataContext` is meaningful, this isn't going to work.

Instead use something like:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("Content.DataContext")
{
  RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self
};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(tab, DataContextProperty, binding);
```

(Depending on your exact requirement you might also want to investigate using Binding.Source instead of Binding.RelativeSource.)

The RelativeSource setting specifies that the binding is to *the same element as the binding target* rather than to the local DataContext -- thus, the DataContext of the control is now bound to the DataContext of the Content of that same control, as required.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to achieve what you're trying to do with bindings in XAML, but if you're using code behind anyway, you might try the following instead:

```
FrameworkElement fe = tab.Content as FrameworkElement
if (fe != null)
    tab.DataContext = fe.DataContext;
```

Without any binding.

Comment: Won't compile.  Content is declared as type object, and object doesn't have a DataContext property.